# Java - Mysql Getter/Setter

Tags: java, mysql

I'm newbie in java, I use getter and setter, as the user authentic.
- How to add a query in the getter and setter?
- How to use ResultSet, Statement on getter and setter?

Excuse my English, is very lousy.
Thanks for your reply

My Class Connection

```
    public class con {
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tienda";
    String user = "root";
    String pw = "";
    Connection conn = null;
public ResultSet iList(String iSql){
       try{
           Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
           Connection oCnn  = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pw);
           PreparedStatement oPst = oCnn.prepareStatement(iSql);
           ResultSet oRst = oPst.executeQuery();
           return oRst;
       }catch(Exception e){
           return null;
       }
   }
   public String Exen(String iSql){
       try{
           Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
           Connection oCnn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pw);
           PreparedStatement oPst = oCnn.prepareStatement(iSql);
           int i= oPst.executeUpdate();
           return null;
       }catch(Exception e){
           return "error "+e.getMessage();
       }
   }
}
```

My User Getter and setter

```
public class usuario {
   conexion cn = new con();
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String lastn;
    private String dir;
    private String iPass;

    public String Eliminau(){
        String cad ="delete from tblusuario where idusuario='" + this.getId() + "'";
        return cn.Ejecutar(cad);
    }
    public String Login(){
        String cad = "SELECT * FROM tblusuario WHERE name  '" + this.getname() + "' AND pass = '"+
                this.getiPass() + "'";
        return cn.Ejecutar(cad);
    }

    public String agregar(){
        String cad = "INSERT INTO tblusuario VALUES('" + 
                this.getId() + "','" + this.getiPass() + "','" + this.getname() + "','" +
                this.getlastn() + "','" + this.getDir() +"')";
        return cn.Ejecutar(cad);
    }

    public String getId() { return id;}

    public void setId(String id) {this.id = id;}

    public String getname() { return name;}

    public void setname(String name) {this.name = name;}

    public String getlastn() {return lastn;}

    public void setlastn(String lastn) {this.lastn = lastn;}

    public String getDir() {return dir;}

    public void setDir(String dir) {this.dir = dir; }

    public String getiPass() { return iPass;}

    public void setiPass(String iPass) {
        String cript;
        cript = DigestUtils.md5Hex(iPass);
        this.iPass = cript;
    }    
}
```

Comment: What is that you exactly want? You obviously know how to use `getter` and `setter`, so what is your question exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your whole code is kinda badly composed. Don't return `ResultSet` or `Statement` at all. Best idea is to use [DAO design pattern](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jdbc/dataaccessobjectdesignpattern.html) which will ensure clean code at least.

Also, in that example, it's shown how to use `PreparedStatement` to prevent SQL injection vulnerability. And your code is quite vulnerable.
Here is [mkyongs](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jdbc-tutorials/) tutorial about JDBC too.

Here is [my GitHub project about JDBC](https://github.com/BranislavLazic/JdbcTutorials) too. Made just for cases like yours. Download it and test it.

Comment: @user1920626 I updated my answer with link to my GitHub JdbcTutorial project.

Comment: Thanks... there is any environment in which you can communicate with you?